# Please re-check my question which has been closed as duplicate, I do not agree it is a duplicate

Tags: discussion, questions

Once upon a time I was challenged to "post an example on Meta" when I found a similar, but different, question being blocked as a duplicate.

My question, "[Why would it be logical to call clearance delivery prior to CTAF during an instrument approach?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67526/why-would-it-be-logical-to-call-clearance-delivery-prior-to-ctaf-during-an-instr)", is not asking *why a CTAF appears on the plate*, but rather why it appears **in the order that it does**.

My question was marked as a duplicate of, "[Why is the clearance delivery frequency included on an approach plate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26295/why-is-the-clearance-delivery-frequency-included-on-an-approach-plate)".  This question asks about the existence of the frequency on the plate, but it fails to address the reasoning for the order of it being on the plate.

When we get these near tangents to other questions and mark them as duplicate, do we not effectively make the ability to obtain an answer via Stack indefinitely impossible.  Now, my question has no answer on either question.  Note that the other question's example has the clearance delivery frequency at the end rather than before CTAF and therefore could not possibly address my question.

If someone else had this same question:

A) they would not find the answer on the "primary" question.

B) they would not find the answer on the question marked as a duplicate

C) they could not ask the real question because I already have and it was shot down as a false duplicate.

Comment: I've edited your subject line to be less..... clickbaity..... your question is of course re-opened. Sometimes good questions get closed as duplicate, sometimes they get re-opened naturally, sometimes a meta discussion is warranted. But please try to avoid the inflammatory titles. Thanks

Comment: @Jamiec where can we have an extended discussion about this in meta?  My question was not intended to be about a single occurrence.  I was challenged in the past to "bring this up in meta once I could identify a clear example" of near-similar questions being indefinitely blocked. Yes, I know here it was subsequently unblocked, but that is not always the case.  If we can't discuss the issue (ie. title is now altered here to be far more specific and not address the general issue which raises more often than it should), then it may never truly be resolved.

Comment: perhaps try with a little less... how do I put it... "incendiary" title. You know similar questions are not "impossible to ask" as you've proved with the example here it wasn't the case. You're unlikely to change the policy on closing duplicates, but if there is a specific policy you want re-examined then by all means post it with some reasoned arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think your question does seem like a distinct question and not a duplicate, so I cast a vote to reopen it.

As for your title question:

> Why do we make some questions nearly impossible to ask due to similar questions?

I'm not sure if that's a sincere question or a rhetorical question, but in any case, presumably we don't do it on purpose. We make mistakes sometimes.